# What is wrong with the following PHP Simple Watermark Maker? It isn't getting image in POST method

Tags: php, html, web-applications

I'm new to php. Just for curiosity, I wanted to build a simple watermark maker using PHP. But when I excuted the below code in GET method, it works perfectly. But It isn't working if I modify it and write POST instead of GET. I written the HTML form code perfectly, but The Form isn't appearing. What to do?
*The 'logo.png' is the watermark image file should be kept in the same directory of the index.php file.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
<?php
header('content-type: image/png');

if (isset($_POST['file'])) {

    $source = $_POST['file'];
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('logo.png');
    $watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
    $watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);


    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

    $image_size = getimagesize($source);
    $x = $image_size[0] - $watermark_width - 10;
    $y = $image_size[1] - $watermark_height - 10;

    imagecopymerge ($image, $watermark, $x, $y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 20);
    imagepng($image);

}
else {
    echo 'No Source';
}   
?>
```

Comment: To get files with php you have to use $_FILES, they are not in the $_POST array

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned in the comment use $_FILES array for file uploads. $_POST will not have 'file'. So change

   `if (isset($_POST['file']))` to `if (isset($_FILES['file']))`
2. change `$source = $_POST['file']` to `$source = $_FILES['file']`
3. You should have uploaded the file first before you use `$image = imagecreatefrompng($source);` and also make sure you "logo.png" in your working directory.

Please find the complete code below:

```
`if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
echo "File is set<br/>";
print_r($_POST); // This will pritn $_POST array
echo "<br/>";
$source = $_FILES['file'];
if(!empty($source)){
    print_r($source); // this will print the $_FILES array
    echo "<br/>";


    $uploads_dir = 'E:\xampp\htdocs\practice\challenge\ ';
    $name = $source['name'];
    if (is_uploaded_file($source['tmp_name'])){
        //in case you want to move  the file in uploads directory
        move_uploaded_file($source['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir.$name);
        echo 'moved file to destination directory';
        exit;
    }
}`
```

Comment: @tawsiftorabi  Can you please give more info? Did you get any error? If so can you post it.

Comment: Not getting any errors. It's just a blank webpage with a small square in it. It worked when I ran it in GET array (like localhost/water/index.php?file=image.png ). It worked perfectly then.

But I want to give it a file upload ($_FILES array) option instead of GET array. I have made a form in another HTML file. But not working. PHP file is not getting images from the HTML file.

Comment: @tawsiftorabi the reason why you are getting a small square in the top-left hand corner is because of your header function. This is the correct form `<?php
header('Content-Type: image\png');
?>`. This should be your first line of your file before you output anything. It should be added above `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Check this link for more info [here](http://afishel.com/LearnHTML/lessons/lesson18.php). Feel free to contact if you need more help. Thanks

Comment: I'll. Thanks @pragin-m

Comment: But why the FILES array work? I have written the html form correctly.
You can see code, http://pastebin.com/mLN4Df0c

Comment: @tawsiftorabi Sorry. I did not get your question. If you meant why the $_FILES array work and not $POST. Well they are both predefined global variables call "supergloabals" in PHP. For more info please refer this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp). If you think my answer is correct and helped you please give it a green tick, or else ask more questions happy to help. thanks